# Create slanted / irregular shape div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to know if it's possible to create this type of div shape with CSS3.

[image: example]

I'm aware you can do things such as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdQzH/) using border's, but is there anyway to get the borders like in the image (spanning he entire top and bottom of the div) - and for bonus points, for it to do it responsively (% widths?)

```
.cornered {
  width: 160px;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid red;
  border-right: 40px solid white;
}
```

Any links, fiddles, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: [Clipping and Masking With CSS](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/)

Comment: You could use the CSS triangle technique you mentioned and then clip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I have created a skewed triangle (if you remove the padding CSS you will see), and then added padding so that you can't see the tip of the triangle

```
.cornered {
    width: 160px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 280px solid blue;
    padding:60px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ExQK/2)

Comment: Does this only work with fix widths? In my implementation of this I need it to stretch the entire page, with the end of the triangle you hid with `clip` overflowing the page (with overflow hidden). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use % based values in either clip, nor border. Thus, I don't think it's possible to create a CSS only solution for you. However, using jQuery you could manually set the px values on page load and resize?

Comment: With your updated fiddle, I played around and just decided to set the highest width my page will be (1200px) and then place it in a container with `overflow: hidden;` and this gives me the effect I needed. So thank you very much for you help! http://jsfiddle.net/2ExQK/3/

Comment: Ah brilliant! No worries.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

css

```
.irregular-shape {
            border-left: 1500px solid black;

            padding: 50px;
            border-top: 100px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
        }
```

markup

```
<div class="irregular-shape"></div>
```